# C# Linq filter DataTable using array elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq

I want filter the data in a data table using `linq`.

My scenario is I have an array of elements which contains dates created dynamically and in the data table we have columns as `id,date,etc.`

We have to retrieve the id's which contains all the dates in array

ex:

```
string[] arr={"10/10/2012","11/11/2012","9/9/2012"}
```

Table :

```
ID   date      
1    10/10/2012         
2    11/11/2012        
1    9/9/2012         
6    9/9/2012         
3    9/9/2012         
6    11/11/2012         
1    11/11/2012
```

Output would be 1 - because only id '1' has all the array elements.

To accomplish above functionality I am using the Linq query shown below. But I am literally failing.

```
Dim volunteers As DataTable =
    (From leftTable In dtavailableVolunteers.AsEnumerable()
    Join rightTable In dtavailableVolunteers.AsEnumerable()
        On leftTable.VolunteerId Equals rightTable.VolunteerId
    Where SelectedDatesArray.All(Function(i) rightTable.Field(Of String)("SelectedDate").Equals(i.ToString()))
    Select rightTable).CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your datatable is dt

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("date in (" + string.join("," , arr) + ")");

string[] st = dr.Select(ss => ss["id"].ToString()).ToArray();
```

OR

```
DataTable newdt = dr.CopyToDataTable();
```

Second line is of LINQ

Comment: This would give you the IDs that match ANY of the dates. The OP's requirement is to match ALL of the dates.

Answer (score 0):

You could group the rows by ID, and then find the groups where: there does not exist an arr element which the group's dates doesn't contain that element.  I mean something like:

```
var result = from item in list
             group item by item.ID into grouping
             where !arr.Exists(date => 
                 !grouping.Select(x => x.Date).Contains(date))
             select grouping.Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```
from volunteer in dtavailableVolunteers
group volunteer by volunteer.Id into g
let volunteerDates = g.Select(groupedElement=>groupedElement.date)
where arr.All(date=>volunteerDates.Contains(date))
select g.Key
```